# Форма в модальном окне (передать данные)

Tags: drupal

У меня есть страница, на ней сейчас расположена ссылка "Добавить" (для открытия кастомной формы в модальном окне) вида:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="use-ajax button button--primary button--action" href="ссылка на форму" data-dialog-type="modal">
            <span>Добавить</span>
</a>
```

Форма открывается нормально. "ссылка на форму" содержит ***get-параметры***. Но мне надо ***в скрытые поля*** этой формы передать данные с текущей страницы.
В голову приходит создать не ссылку "Добавить", а маленькую форму:

```
<form action = "ссылка на форму" method = "post">
 <input type="hidden" value="my_value">
<button class="use-ajax button button--primary button--action" data-dialog-type="modal">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Но в таком случае не происходит открытия формы в модальном окне, идет сразу переход на нее.

А если я пропишу ссылку на форму прямо в кнопке, то происходит открытие в модальном окне, но отправки моих скрытых данных не происходит, т.к. в method ничего не прописано:

```
<form method = "post">
 <input type="hidden" value="my_value">
<button> 
     <a rel="nofollow" class="use-ajax button button--primary button--action" href="ссылка на форму" data-dialog-type="modal">
            <span>Добавить</span>
      </a>
</button>
</form>
```

Может, кто-то знает, как правильно открыть форму в модальном окне, передав в ее скрытые поля данные?

Comment: Вы хотите открывать по ссылке или все же форму? Обычно модальное окно находится там же где и остальная разметка и показывают его просто применив определенные стили, но у Вас видимо другая задумка.

Comment: Мне надо при клике на некоторую кнопку, открыть в модальном окне форму, передав в эту форму некоторое значение, но не через адресную строку.  Форма создана мною программно (class addProduct extends FormBase). В ссылке, на которую нажимаю, указываю роутинг до этой формы. А вывод в модальном окне настраиваю путем указания класса use-ajax и атрибута data-dialog-type="modal"

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите какие-то поля с текущей страницы передавать в форму? У вас какой Drupal?
Если Drupal 8, 9 или 10, тогда в форме, в разделе "Строение", где формируете поля для формы, есть поле "Базовый HTML" или "Скрытый" если вам нужно, что бы не отображался в форме. Там есть "Просмотр доступных токенов". Находите нужный вам и выводите в поле.
Единственное потом нужно будет в настройке отправки Электронных писем вывести это поле для отправки, если нужно, но это не точно, так как может быть это поле по умолчанию будет отправляться. В общем разберётесь.

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли. Drupal 8. Но форма создана мной лично программно (class addProduct extends FormBase).

Comment: @fkdjhfhf я так понял вы свой модуль пишете. Я сам так и не научился модули писать, но вы всё также можете подтягивать нужные вам поля в форму, Не скажу точно как, не извращался так никогда, но можно это точно. Кажется по id вычисляется страница и с этой страницы берёте нужные вам поля в форму.